# issue with importing class in Python

Tags: python

I am making a simple program in Python and I want from one file import a class that I made in another class. My code is the following:

```
#file cPoint.py
import math
class Point:
    def __init__(self,x,y):
        self.x=x
        self.y=y

    def printC(self):
        print ("(",self.x,",",self.y,")")
```

and my other file is:

```
#file pointTest
import cPoint

def main():
    p=Point(3,4)
    p.printC()

if __name__=="__main__":
    main()
```

The problem is that when I run my program from the file pointTest, by the way both of them are in the same directory, I got the following error:

```
 File "E:\python\pointTest.py", line 15, in <module>
    main()

  File "E:\python\pointTest.py", line 11, in main
    p=Point(3,4)

NameError: name 'Point' is not defined
```

When I test my program all in the same file it works, and also when I call the class from the command prompt by using:

```
import cPoint

p=Point(3,4)

p.printC()
( 3 , 4 )
```

what am I missing? I am using WinPython in Anaconda.

Comment: `p=cPoint.Point(3,4)`? or `from cPoint import Point`?

Comment: @Craicerjack, is there not other more direct way to do it? sorry, but I remember that in Python 2.7 it was not needed to do that

Comment: You can do `from cPoint import *` to import everything though it is **not** recommended.

Comment: @Little _I remember that in Python 2.7 it was not needed to do that_ Do you have an example of what you're referring to?

Answer (score 0):

When you call functions or classes from other files, you have to specify where to find them. You can do this by putting the name of the file containing it in front of the function/class name, like this: `cPoint.Point`. This tells testPoint to look for `Point` within cPoint.

Another option is to import the class directly into testPoint instead of the entire file. You can do this by replacing your import statement with `from cPoint import Point`. This will allow you to call `Point` without having to specify which file it is in (you won't need to use `cPoint.Point`, you can just call `Point`).

Because you haven't specified where `Point` is, testPoint only looks for `Point` within itself, and `Point` only exists in cPoint, so it fails to find it, causing an error to be thrown. I hope this answers your question! :)

Answer (score 0):

You've imported the file cPoint.py using

```
import cPoint
```

But you can't access its functions directly like functions of file PointTest.py. A function in the same file can be accessed directly just by its name.

> BUT

A function in another (imported) file can't be accessed directly. Rather you should write:

```
#file pointTest
import cPoint

def main():                  ##
    p=cPoint.Point(3,4)    #### Look at this line written here
    p.printC()               ##

if __name__=="__main__":
    main()
```